# Add Gradle dependency programatically to another Gradle project

Tags: java, gradle

I have a Java Gradle project (let's call it "A") that, by using a 3rd party tool, generates a distinct Java Gradle project (B). Each project has its own build.gradle file.

The problem is that the tool that generates the project B has a bug and it does not add a dependency to the build.gradle file of project B, this leading to a compilation error. For instance, project B should have three dependencies, as it follows:

```
dependencies {
    compile group: 'group-1', name: 'name-1', version: '1.5'
    compile group: 'group-2', name: 'name-2', version: '3.7.2'
    compile group: 'group-3', name: 'name-3', version: '2.4'
}
```

but it has only two:

```
dependencies {
    compile group: 'group-1', name: 'name-1', version: '1.5'
    compile group: 'group-2', name: 'name-2', version: '3.7.2'
}
```

Since I cannot fix this bug in the 3rd party tool that generates the project B, how can I programatically add the missing dependency to project B, from a Gradle task from project A? In the end, I want the build.gradle of project B to look like this:

```
dependencies {
    compile group: 'group-1', name: 'name-1', version: '1.5'
    compile group: 'group-2', name: 'name-2', version: '3.7.2'
    compile group: 'group-3', name: 'name-3', version: '2.4'
}
```

Thank you!

Comment: Can you perhaps share the gradle script on GitHub?